# NavLink returns active to all links and no solution in SO seems to work

Tags: css, reactjs, react-navigation, styled-components, conditional-rendering

It seems none of the solutions presented elsewhere works, so I decided to ask. No matter what I do, I can't get the NavLinks to be rendered differently if they are active or not. I took the ternary operator straight from the part about NavLinks in react-router-dom's documentation and I'd try to create a function to avoid having all this code written three times, but before that I'd like to at least have the correct rendering working.

(side question: why does it break if I remove the Router tags from the return statement? They're there because, before I needed the NavLinks for different styling, I was using regular routes, but if I take them out it breaks with a message about useHref, something like that)

Here's my return statement and the styled-components below it:

```
return (
        <>
            <GlobalStyles />
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <Wrapper>
                    <NavBar>
                        <NavLink
                            to="/search"
                            exact
                            className={(isActive) =>
                                "nav-link" + (!isActive ? " inactive" : "")
                            }>
                            Search song
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink
                            to="/weekly-thread"
                            exact
                            className={(isActive) =>
                                "nav-link" + (!isActive ? " inactive" : "")
                            }>
                            Weekly thread
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink
                            to="/game"
                            exact
                            className={(isActive) =>
                                "nav-link" + (!isActive ? " inactive" : "")
                            }>
                            Game
                        </NavLink>
                    </NavBar>
                </Wrapper>
            </Router>
        </>
    );
};

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
`;
const NavBar = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: relative;
    gap: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav-link {
        color: blue;
        &:inactive {
            color: black;
        }
    }
`;
```

EDIT: it's getting weirder. After even simply pasting the code from the answer below and not getting any results, I tried to mess with the font size for the active NavLink. To my surprise, now something changed, but in totally bizarre way, as it made the first element stay as it were before and second and third got transformed just in terms of font size, but nothing else. When I click on the other NavLinks, the URL changes, but they remain the same: the first in the original size, the other two altered.

SECOND EDIT: Trying to debug this a little further, I've done this to one of my NavLinks and the result is very weird:

```
<NavLink to="/search" exact className={(isActive) => {
    console.log(isActive);
    isActive === false ? console.log(isActive) : console.log("foo");
}}>Search song</NavLink>
```

Now, the first console.log returns the actual value of isActive, but the second and third console.logs always return, "foo", which is the second value in the ternary operator, even if I change "isActive === false" to "isActive === true", which should swap them. I have no idea what is going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After console.logs here, there and everywhere, something struck my attention: isActive appears as an object on the console. That's why I was always getting the same result.

When I changed the condition on the ternary operator to `isActive.isActive ?` I started getting the expected results.

Comment: Looks like their api changed from v5 to v6., they went from `(isActive: boolean) => string` to `(obj: {isActive:boolean}) => string`. the codepen's in my answer are still using v5.

Comment: I see. Anyway, there's a simpler solution up there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

## Router

You might want to read up on the docs.
The [primary components](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components) page explains why you would need a router.
It provides information for the other components; IE what the current route is.

## NavLink

NavLink should be able to set their `active` class themselves, based on if the  router is matching on the `to` props of the `NavLink`

see this [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-99mzf?file=/example.js) for an example.

Note that you would still need need to provide the CSS for the class that is applied. If you're using a framework like bootstrap, or material-ui; they would usually have a `.active` css styling already in there by default.

## CSS

The css rule might be incorrect, there seems to be a colon at `&:inactive` which probable should be `.inactive` class:

```
.nav-link {
    color: blue;
    &.inactive {
      color: black;
    }
  }
```

[codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-ebn2j?file=/example.js:1699-1774)

Comment: I really don't understand. Your codepen works, but even if I paste your code directly in my app I don't get the same results. It's still always showing as if they were all active.

Comment: use the inspector to see if the html-element actually has a class  applied to them.
right-click the link, pick 'inspect' from the menu. wait for it to load, then check if the element has a class like `class="nav-link"` or `class="nav-link inactive"`. if they have a class, then is an error in your css.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. They are all getting class="nav-link". The only difference is that the active one gets aria-current="page" assigned to it as well. Do you know what I can do about it?

Comment: I've done this to one of my NavLinks and the result is very weird:
```
<NavLink to="/search" exact className={(isActive) => {
      console.log(isActive);
      isActive === false ? console.log(isActive) : console.log("false");
}}>Search song</NavLink>
```
Now, the first console.log returns the actual value of isActive, but the second and third console.logs always return the second value in the ternary operator, even if I change "isActive === false" to "isActive === true". I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Fred, why don't you use the .active class that React Router automatically applies to the active NavLink? It would be easier than what you are trying to do with ternary operators. Besides, you don't need an .IsActive AND an .active class on each active NavLink. It's redundant. Also, since there is already an active class, you don't need an inactive class, unless you are required to utilize some CSS that needs these classes...? Here's a CodeSandbox as the one Lars linked to but using React-Router v6. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-g1jsnw?file=/example.js

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove your className property from NavLink.

Remove:

```
className={(isActive) =>
    "nav-link" + (!isActive ? " inactive" : "")
}>
```

It's unnecessary as **React-Router already adds the .active class to the active link**, so what you're doing with that property is no doubt creating the weirdness.

You can just style the a.active however you want.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it and it works, but as it turns out, I took that first suggestion of using className={(isActive etc. from react-router-dom's documentation itself, as you can see here: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/classname-string-func
Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's the docs for v5, but if you have recently installed React-Router you're probably using v6. I believe that has been rolled into 6 natively.

Comment: Oh well now this is confusing.  The docs seem to suggest the opposite of what I just said. "In React Router v6, activeClassName will be removed and you should use the function className to apply classnames to either active or inactive NavLink components."

Comment: Oh, documentation is a whole problem in itself... Anyway, things are working now and thanks for the help.